# How to apply the color of a particular cell to the entire row in all rows using excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, conditional-formatting

I am an absolute newbie to VBA and am trying to color all the rows in a sheet based on the conditional formatting of a particular column (Y). The column Y has been conditionally formatted using a 3 point color scale, so that each unique numerical value has a distinct color. I would now like to have every individual row in this sheet the same color as the value of the cell in the Y column of that row.

Looking at examples on the web and modifying the code slightly the following works by coloring the entire Row 3 in the conditionally formatted color of the cell Y3:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.Range("3:3").Interior.Color = Me.Range("Y3").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

My question is how can I introduce a loop here so that every nth row takes the value of the cell Yn.

Thanks for your time and support.

Comment: loop through rows

Comment: Why not apply the conditional format to the whole row, based on the Y column value?

Comment: @TimWilliams - since it's a color scale based on the cell value, isn't that not an option?

Comment: @BigBen - yes I guess you're right - OP please ignore my suggestion, unless you want to switch to formula-based Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. @TimWilliams, I am ready to use any method that will work. :-) Unfortunately, I am completely in the dark about most of the VBA terminology.

Comment: @HTH, how could one loop through rows here. I tried 'For n 0= 1 to 100 Me.Range(n:n).Interior.Color = Me.Range("Y"&n).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color Next n'  But that seems to be erroneous. –

Comment: `Me.Rows(n).Interior.Color`.

Comment: @BigBen - Thank you very much. That worked like a charm. Now all I need is a suggestions for a good starting book on VBA and to look forward to being a regular here.

Comment: Hmm - there's many books. I might also point you to the [VBA Rubberducking chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking).

Comment: I started with "Excel 2016 Power Programming with VBA" (OK back then it was Excel 95, but I'm guessing still a good "foundation" book for Excel VBA)

Comment: BigBen & TimWilliams - Thank you for the resources. I now have my reading cut out for me:  "Excel 2016 Power Programming with VBA" interspersed with trying my hand at the VBA Rubberducking chat room. Thanks again for the help with the code.